# mount.nfs4 just 'hangs'

Tags: mount, nfs, client

I have an NFS server running Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 with KRB5.

I have three NFS clients working (2x Linux Mint 17.1 and 1x Crunchbang)
I have one NFS client that just hangs when I run mount.nfs4.

As far as I can tell, I have everything set-up correctly.

Exports:

```
/zfs/biz/dcp            172.16.0.0/21(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=krb5,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/zfs/biz/it             172.16.0.0/21(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=krb5,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/zfs/bikeshed/backupz   172.16.0.0/21(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=krb5,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
/zfs/media/movies       172.16.0.0/21(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=krb5,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534)
/zfs/media/music        172.16.0.0/21(rw,no_subtree_check,root_squash,async,sec=krb5,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534)
```

I have configured /etc/default/nfs-common with 
    NEED_GSSD=yes
    NEED_IDMAPD=yes

I have the following included in idmapd:
    [Mapping]

```
Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup
```

The following processes are running on the client:

```
root       494     2  0 18:39 ?        00:00:00 [rpciod]
root       531     1  0 18:39 ?        00:00:00 rpc.idmapd
root      3769     1  0 20:59 ?        00:00:00 rpc.gssd
root      4390     1  0 21:07 ?        00:00:00 rpcbind -w
statd     4396     1  0 21:07 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd -L
```

And I have the relevant krb5.conf and krb5.keytabs.
The output I see when running rpc.gssd -vvvf and rpc.svcgssd -vvvf is identical for both working and none-working clients.

My server's krb5.log file shows tickets getting issued.

The only difference I can see in is packet capture. In the non-successful case the client does not respond to SETCLIENTID with a SETCLIENTID_CONFIRM packet, where as in a successful case the client **does** respond.

I figure there's something somewhere in the configuration of this one client that is wrong, but I'm missing it.

What can cause a client not to return a SETCLIENTID_CONFIRM message when using the NFS protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found two causes of this behaviour and a resolution for each, which I will post for future reference.

Initially this was caused by a missing package. Resolved by:

```
 sudo apt-get install libpam-krb5
```

I also saw the same problem re-occur when reverse DNS is broken - check that both forward and reverse DNS look-ups work with the following commands, substituting in your clients FQDN and IP address:

```
nslookup mynfsclienthostname.domain.internal
nslookup 192.168.1.5
```

If either fails you need to find out why and resolve that issue.

Comment: Thanks! Changing from IP address to domain name fixed the problem for me. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: nslookup helped me realize that I had the IP of my server wrong.

Comment: Indeed I confirm that the libpam-kerb5 package installation solves the problem. It is strange then that no dependency exists between nfs packages and this package !